# Jumping between functions in tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter

so I am working on this school project and I need to be able to run the random number generator then if it is 1 go to the headspinner module but if it is 2 go to the tailspinner module. After that the code should add up the score and print it to the user.
Any advice on how to jump from one function to another in my code would be much appreciated thank you.

```
from tkinter import * # access tkinter library
import random # get random number generator


money = 100


#create coin flip module
def coinFlip():

    flip = random.randint(1, 2)
    if flip == 1:
        headspinner()
    else:
        tailspinner()
        
#create headspinner module
def headspinner():
    global money
    head = random.randint(1, 2)
    if head == 1:
        money = money + 30
    else:
        money = money - 25

#create tailspinner module
def tailspinner():
    global money
    tail = random.randint(1, 4)
    if tail == 1:
        money = money + 2
    elif tail == 2:
        money = money + 5
    elif tail == 3:
        money = money + 10
    else:
        money = money + 15

#gains or losses module
def upordown():
    global money
    if money > 100:
        screen.itemconfig(message, text = f"Congratulations, you won ${(money - 100):.2f}", font = ("Calibri", "18")) 
    else:
        screen.itemconfig(message, text = f"Congratulations, you won ${(100 - money):.2f}", font = ("Calibri", "18"))
    
   


#create pop up box
root = Tk()

#creating canvas
screen = Canvas (root, height = 600, width = 800, bg = "lightgreen")
screen.pack()

#flip button
go = Button(root, text = "Flip", cursor = "hand2", command = coinFlip)
goButton = screen.create_window(400, 530, window = go)

#cerate title
title = screen.create_text(400, 100, text = "Welcome to Flip and Spin", font = ("Calibri", "35"))


#text for instructions
text1 = Label(root, text = "Welcome to the Flip and Spin game! \nThis game includes a quick fate of what you could encounter. \nIt starts off with a fast flip of a coin followed by a dizzying spin of a spinner. \nCome and play to decide if you will lose money, \nmake your money back, or win some easy money!", font = ("Calibri", "20"), justify = CENTER, bg = "light green")
text1label = screen.create_window(400, 300, window = text1,)



#text for final results
message = screen.create_text(400, 400, text = "Results", font = ("Calibri", "18"))



#close canvas
mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't jump between functions; you *call* them, just as shown in the many tutorials on the topic.  When the function is done, it returns to its caller, which then does the next thing, whatever that might be.  You've described what you intend to do; please specify where you're having trouble to code this.  You posted over 60 lines of code to ask a 10-line question.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).

Comment: Be sure to read [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/) and [this one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html).

Comment: What if the `money` variable is less than or equal to 0? You subtract here: `money = money - 25`.

Comment: I think you need to call `upordown()` at the end of `coinFlip()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are already switching from function to function in `def coinFlip`.

You just need to put everything together.

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, X, LEFT, RIGHT
import random


money = 100


#create coin flip module
def coin_flip():
    flip = random.randint(1, 2)
    if flip == 1:
        headspinner()
    else:
        tailspinner()

#create headspinner module
def headspinner():
    global money
    head = random.randint(1, 2)
    if head == 1:
        money = money + 30
    else:
        money = money - 25
    text.config(text=f"Headspinner: {money}", bg="#aaafff")
    

#create tailspinner module
def tailspinner():
    global money
    tail = random.randint(1, 4)
    if tail == 1:
        money = money + 2
    elif tail == 2:
        money = money + 5
    elif tail == 3:
        money = money + 10
    else:
        money = money + 15
    text.config(text=f"Tailspinner: {money}", bg="#ffaaaa")

def show_result():
    global money
    text.config(text=f"Result: {money}.\nClick the Flip button to start over.", bg="#fffaaa")
    money = 100 # reset
    
        
root = Tk()
root.title("Game")

# the text here changes when the buttons are pressed
text = Label(root, text="Welcome to the Flip and Spin game!", font = ("Calibri", "18"))
text.pack()

rules = Label(root, text="This game includes a quick fate of what you could encounter. \nIt starts off with a fast flip of a coin followed by a dizzying spin of a spinner. \nCome and play to decide if you will lose money, \nmake your money back, or win some easy money!", font = ("Calibri", "10"))
rules.pack()

# click the button to run the command and change the text in the Label
flip_button = Button(root, text="Flip", command=coin_flip, fg="blue")
flip_button.pack(fill=X, side=LEFT, expand=True)

# click the button to run the command and change the text in the Label
result_button = Button(root, text="Result", command=show_result, fg="blue")
result_button.pack(fill=X, side=RIGHT, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```